# How to add As Clause (type) to a property created with SyntaxFactory?

Tags: vb.net, code-generation, roslyn, microsoft.codeanalysis

I am creating a property with `SyntaxFactory` (roslyn)

```
Dim [property] = SyntaxFactory .PropertyStatement("MyProperty").AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory .Token(SyntaxKind.FriendKeyword))
```

The result is

> Friend Property MyProperty

To add the property type I probably need to use *[WithAsClause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.visualbasic.syntax.propertystatementsyntax.withasclause)*, but I can't find any usable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to find an example in [Syntax Factory Tests:TestSpacingOnNullableDatetimeType](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.UnitTests/Syntax/SyntaxFactoryTests.vb,33) and a solution is

```
Dim [property] = SyntaxFactory.PropertyStatement("MyProperty").AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.FriendKeyword)).
            WithAsClause(SyntaxFactory.SimpleAsClause(
            SyntaxFactory.PredefinedType(
               SyntaxFactory.Token(
                  SyntaxKind.StringKeyword))))
```

which has the desired result

> Friend Property MyProperty As String